# Does it hurt to run php in integrated mode under IIS 7?

Tags: php, asp.net, iis

I tested that on same website asp.net 4 and php works but only in integrated mode not in classic mode. I thought php required classic so if it works in integrated mode also what's bad ?

Comment: I would say that it hurts to run PHP on IIS generally, but that's more because of IIS then PHP^ ^ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of my PHP-powered sites that run under IIS 7 are using Integrated mode -- no issues at all, although I do not have mix of ASP.NET & PHP -- only "old plain" ASP (few basic pages that work with SQL Server & WinHttp.WinHttpRequest) & PHP (+ WinCache extension)